# C++: Singleton? How to pass arguments to the construtors?

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I am reading Item 47 in "Effective C++". In the book it is suggested that the so called non-local static objects should be used with special care. Instead it suggests to use something like below:

```
Directory& tempDir()  
{  
         static Directory td;  
         return td;  
}
```

I am not so sure if it should be called as singleton. However, I am thinking how I can pass arguments to the constructor of class Directory. For instance, I want to pass a path as a string to Directory td, perhaps I need to do it like this:

```
Directory& tempDir(std::string & str)  
{  
         static Directory td(str);  
         return td;  
}
```

The problem is that whenever I want to access Directory td, I have to pass the string as the input argument. This is not so beautiful.

Does anyone have more elegant way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have more elegant way of doing this?

Instead of passing the path in the function, write a global function which "generates" the path:

```
char const* get_path()
{
    // do_stuff and return the path
}

Directory& tempDir()  
{  
         static Directory td(get_path());  
         return td;  
}
```

The better way would be not to use a singleton though. Create the object in the `main()`-function, initialize it there and pass it by reference for all components.

> You can of course have default parameter values like `Directory& tempDir(const std::string & str = "")` , if this is of any help for your use case.

That's nonsense. Creating a temporary every time you call this function is completely unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Function-local objects with `static` linkage are only initialised _once_, so you wouldn't be creating a temporary every time you call this function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the temporary is for the function parameter. The compiler still has to create an empty string for the default value each time the function is called without parameters.

Comment: @TheDark: Oh, a temporary for the _function_? I thought it was for the `Directory` constructor for some reason. Then yes.

Comment: @Arcoth Thank you. The situation is that I need an object that should be accessed globally and this object should also be initialized after entry to main. In addition, I don't need more than one instance. Therefore I thought about singleton.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, i meant the temporary which is bound to the reference in the function parameter. :)

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you wish to initialize the global instance, but then access it as a singleton.

You can do it like this:

```
class Directory
{ 
public: 
    Directory& tempDir(const std::string & str)
    {
        if (tempDir_ == nullptr)
        {
            tempDir_ = new Directory(str);
        }
        return *tempDir_;
    }
    Directory& tempDir()
    {
        assert(tempDir_);
        // Or throw an execption etc.
        return *tempDir_;
    }

private:
    Directory(const std::string & str)
    {
        // etc.
    }
    static Directory* tempDir_;
};
```

Obviously, you need to make sure that initialization call does happen first, or restructure the approach.

Also, you might prefer to change `tempDir(const std::string & str)` to `initialiseTempDir(const std::string & str)` or some such.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion.

Keep the first version of `tempDir`.

```
Directory& tempDir()  
{  
   static Directory td;  
   return td;  
}
```

Add a member function to `Directory` to set the path. When you need to set the path, use:

```
tempDir().setPath(path);
```

Using this approach allows creation of singletons that have state. You can get and set other state associated with the singleton using similar accessor and modifier functions.